# Data is not getting added in arraylist for radiogroup?

Tags: android, arraylist, radio-button, radio-group

I want to add data in ArrayList  "arr" according to the checkedId of the radio group.I have 4 radio buttons "a0,a1,a2,a3". So if I chose a1,the array list should add the value of rb2. And after selecting a1 if I select a2 then the previous value in "arr" should get updated (not get added after the first one) and  so on.Any help..

```
   rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= mcq.size(); i++) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.a0:
                        // do operations specific to this selection

                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                rb1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.a1:
                        // do operations specific to this selection

                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                rb2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.a2:
                        // do operations specific to this selection

                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                rb3.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.a3:
                        // do operations specific to this selection

                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                rb4.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }
                arr.add(String.valueOf(checkedId));
                Log.e("", String.valueOf(arr));
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

```
SparaseArray<Boolean> array = new SparseArray();
array.put(checkedId, rb.isChecked());
```

Then you can get all the checked elements of the array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< sparseArray.size(); i++) {
   int id = sparseArray.keyAt(i);
   Boolean isChecked = sparseArray.get(id);
   if(isChecked) {
       log("Identifier " + id + " is checked");
   }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "cannot  resolve symbol".Do I have to define its size first.@AlexanderKulyakhtin